# jQuery Fadein Page on Anchor Click Problem

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with loading external pages into a DIV using jQuery.

I want to include an external page into a specific DIV when an anchor link is clicked.

**The problem is** when I click a link, and after the external page has loaded it removed the rest of the page's content after it :/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ahah(url, target) {
  document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = ' Fetching data...';
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (req != undefined) {
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {ahahDone(url, target);};
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send("");
  }
}  

function ahahDone(url, target) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = req.responseText;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=" AHAH Error:\n"+ req.status + "\n" +req.statusText;
    }
  }
}

function load(name, div) {
    ahah(name,div);
    return false;
}

</script>

<div id="content"></div>


<a href="file1.html" onclick="load('page.php','content');return false;">File 1</a>
```

Can anyone help, Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged `jQuery` Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't think it through :/ any thoughts though?

Comment: Maybe you should answer @The Scrum Meister's question. Do you have jQuery loaded or not?

Comment: The jQuery library is loaded on the same page yes.

Comment: Your example works here http://jsfiddle.net/SXwPE/, Are you sure it is removing the page's content after it? Try moving the div after the link. see if the link stays there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guess could be that `page.php` returns a full html document, including `</body>` and `</html>` tags, thus making your browser not render any of the original page content after these tags.

Comment: Good point Klaus, But sadly no it doesn't. It's actually just a couple of PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any jQuery being used here, but if you wouldn't mind replacing what you have with jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#someanchorid").click(function() {
        $("#yourdiv").load("file1.html");
        return false;
    });
});
```